# Como cerrar una ventana modal con un botón

Tags: javascript, html, modal

espero puedan ayudarme estaba viendo un código aquí donde al picar una imagen te manda a un modal  mas grande donde muestra mas grande la misma imagen, y yo quise replicar lo mismo pero con un botón que me mostrara después la sola imagen, hice un un botón algo similar pero la parte del botón de cerrar la imagen una vez que me la muestra no me quiere agarrar, alguien me podría apoyar.

No se, si igual por el modal y no tener el mismo nombre me agarre mal , o si es un proceso mas del botón .

De antemano gracias

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="codigo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>CliffPedia</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

.modal {
    display: none; 
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: 1; 
    padding-top: 100px; 
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: auto; 
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); 
}

.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

.modal-content, #caption { 
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}


    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Large modal -->
<button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">Large modal</button>

<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="popUp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="img-container">
 
       <img id="myImg" src="http://joportal.hu/images/news/3fc2302101eccde9b8f57cb13b79e65df0ffcd15.jpg">

       <!--<div id="popUp" class="modal">
       <span class="close">&times;</span>
       <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
       <div id="caption"></div>
       </div> -->

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var modal = document.getElementById('popUp');

var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer se está generando un **`div`** encima de todo el modal e impide que puedas seleccionar la **`X`** porque el **`div`** está encima del todo cubriéndolo. Este **`div`** que se genera tiene la clase **`.modal-backdrop`**, tan solo bastaría ocultarlo agregando las siguientes propiedades en tu **`css`**:

```
.modal-backdrop {
  display: none;  
}
```

Puedes ver el resultado final [**aquí**](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/MWXJaQm).

Comment: solo una duda esa como cortina blanca es igual del modal ? porque se ve como un rectángulo blanco en la imagen